# How to create a class variable based on several indicator variables

Tags: sas

I have a dataset of clinical test results. I want to create a "results" variable based on the variable names of the tests that the patients were positive for. This may be taken care of by many if-else statements, but I want to be able to build a character variable that accounts for multiple test results without having to know the various response patterns a priori.

This is an example of the dataset:

```
ID  RSV         FLU
1   Positive    Negative
2   Negative    Positive
3   Negative    Negative
4   Positive    Positive
5   Negative    Negative
```

This is what I am looking for:

```
ID  RSV         FLU         Result
1   Positive    Negative    RSV
2   Negative    Positive    FLU
3   Negative    Negative    
4   Positive    Positive    RSV, FLU
5   Negative    Negative
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How many variables do you have?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used proc transpose to invert the dataset, with this approach you can have as many columns as needed for clinical test outcome

```
/*Input Dataset*/
data have;
input ID RSV$ FLU$;
datalines;
1 Positive Negative
2 Negative Positive
3 Negative Negative
4 Positive Positive
5 Negative Negative
;
run;

proc sort data=have; by id; run;

/*Initial Transpose*/
proc transpose data=have out=want0;
by id;
var rsv flu;
run;

/*Manipulate transposed dataset*/
data want1;
length Result $50.;
 set want0;
  by id;
  retain Result '';

  if first.id then Result='';
  if first.id and col1='Positive' then Result=_NAME_;
  else if not first.id and col1='Positive' then Result=catx(', ',Result,_NAME_);
  if last.id;
run;

/*Final outcome*/
proc sql;
create table want
as
select a.*, b.result
  from have a
  left join want1 b
  on a.id=b.id;
quit;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need to build off of. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

An array and VNAME() are likely good options here. Untested.

```
data want;
   set have;
   array diags(*) RSV FLU;*list variables here;
   length diags_combined $256.;

   do i=1 to dim(diags);
     if diag(i) = 'Positive' then catx(', ', diags_combined, vname(diag(i)));
   end;
 run;
```

Comment: Thank you, @Reeza! I tried this as well, but the code doesn't account for multiple positives.

Comment: By multiple positives do you mean each record having more than one positive? Because that's definitely accounted for.